# How to keep changes inside a container on the host after a docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose dev stack. When I run, `docker-compose up --build`, the container will be built and it will execute

Dockerfile:

```
RUN composer install --quiet
```

That command will write a bunch of files inside the `./vendor/` directory, which is then only available inside the container, as expected. The also existing `vendor/` on the host is not touched and, hence, out of date.

Since I use that container for development and want my changes to be available, I mount the current directory inside the container as a volume:

docker-compose.yml:

```
my-app:
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/myapp/
```

This loads an outdated `vendor` directory into my container; forcing me to rerun `composer install` either on the host or inside the container in order to have the up to date version.

I wonder how I could manage my docker-compose stack differently, so that the changes during the docker build on the current folder are also persisted on the host directory and I don't have to run the command twice.

I do want to keep the `vendor` folder mounted, as some `vendors` are my own and I like being able to modifiy them in my current project. So only mounting the folders I need to run my application would not be the best solution.

I am looking for a way to tell docker-compose: Write all the stuff inside the container back to the host before adding the volume.

Comment: @ZeRubeus I most of the time do. Sometimes a rebuilt is necessary, though. And then I would like to avoid rerunning a command.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a short side container after `docker-compose build`:

```
docker run --rm -v /vendor:/target my-app cp -a vendor/. /target/.
```

The `cp` could also be something more efficient like an `rsync`. Then after that container exits, you do your `docker-compose up` which mounts /vendor from the host.

Answer (score 1):

> Write all the stuff inside the container back to the host before adding the volume.

There isn't any way to do this directly, but there are a few options to do it as a second command.

- as already suggested you can run a container and copy or rsync the files
- use `docker cp` to copy the files out of a container (without using a volume)
- use a tool like [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) (disclaimer: dobi is my own project) to automate these tasks. You can use one image to update `vendor`, and another image to run the application. That way updates are done on the host, but can be built into the final image. `dobi` takes care of skipping unnecessary operations when the artifact is still fresh (based on modified time of files or resources), so you never run unnecessary operations.

Comment: Is dobi your own project? If so, please add a disclaimer.

Comment: Thanks I will do that